# Owl Carousel 2 animation not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have followed this instructions, but the slider not do the fadeOut and fadeIn animation: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/animate.html

**Head Css:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
```

**Html item:**

```
<div id="product-designs-presentation" class="owl-carousel">
    <div style="width:186px">
        <img src="svg/shirt-design-1.svg" alt="">a
    </div>
    <div style="width:186px">
        <img src="svg/shirt-design-2.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#product-designs-presentation').owlCarousel({
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        items:1,
        autoPlay:true,
        autoPlayTimeout:1000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        navigation: true,
        navigationText: ["prev","next"]
    });
});

</script>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed class `class='owl-carousel'`this is needed for owl-carousel working. I think this is the problem [owl docs](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/started-installation.html)

```
<div id="product-designs-presentation" class="owl-carousel">
    <div style="width:186px">
        <img src="svg/shirt-design-1.svg" alt="">a
    </div>
    <div style="width:186px">
        <img src="svg/shirt-design-2.svg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Use this [css](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css) this is working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#product-designs-presentation').owlCarousel({
       animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        items:1,
        autoPlay:true,
        autoPlayTimeout:1000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        navigation: true,
        navigationText: ["prev","next"]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>




<div id="product-designs-presentation" class="owl-carousel">
  <div style="width:186px">
    <img src="http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/095/621/original/free-leaf-vector.png" alt="">a
  </div>
  <div style="width:186px">
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/15/29/maple-149907_960_720.png" alt="">b
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Owl Carousel script add this class automatically

Comment: @FunnyFrontend i think you have to read this [doc](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/started-installation.html)

Comment: @FunnyFrontend and yes `class="item"` is not mandatory but `class='owl-carousel'` is must

Comment: @FunnyFrontend  I don't know where is the problem once i connected normal cdn owl css its not working but i use [this css](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css) this is working ... [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKYdVG)

Comment: thanks man, the true problem was my owl.js version, I copy your js codepen